# Texas Hold'em, what's the winning hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em

Hero: A⋄4⋄

Villain: K♣3⋄

Board: 3♥4♠K♠6♠6♣

Who wins the showdown?

Comment: Kings and sixes would beat fours and sixes.

Answer (score 0):

Poker hands have exactly 5 cards, no more, no fewer.

Your hand is **6s 6c 4s 4d Ad** : two pair, sixes and fours, ace.
His hand is **Ks Kc 6s 6c 4s** : two pair, kings and sixes, four.

He wins.